AMD Graphics card drivers are not installing
I did a clean reinstall of windows 11 pro after I added SSD to my laptop. Now it is not working and showing confusing error messages I have attached pictures I also did a clean install for my drivers using DDU but it is still not working and now it is completely gone from device manager. I need help Please It worked perfectly at first and now it doesn't my specs That I know of are as under (card model  no is acting wierdly it is actually R5 M520 it worked fine before installing SSD)

I am also copypasting system info that I exported below please tell me if anyone has a solution
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro    
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621  
Other OS Description    Not Available   
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation   
System Name BLACKDELL   
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.   
System Model    Inspiron 3576   
System Type x64-based PC    
System SKU  083F    
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 1992 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)   
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.16.0, 12/16/2021    
SMBIOS Version  2.8 
Embedded Controller Version 255.255 
BIOS Mode   Legacy  
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Dell Inc.   
BaseBoard Product   0J11DH  
BaseBoard Version   A00 
Platform Role   Mobile  
Secure Boot State   Unsupported 
PCR7 Configuration  Binding Not Possible    
Windows Directory   C:\Windows  
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32 
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1 
Locale  United States   
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.22621.2506" 
User Name   BLACKDELL\Wajih 
Time Zone   Pakistan Standard Time  
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB 
Total Physical Memory   15.8 GB 
Available Physical Memory   8.17 GB 
Total Virtual Memory    24.3 GB 
Available Virtual Memory    15.5 GB 
Page File Space 8.50 GB 
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys 
Kernel DMA Protection   Off 
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled 
Device Encryption Support   Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not Modern Standby, TPM is not usable   
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes 
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes 
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes 
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes 

[Hardware Resources]



[Conflicts/Sharing]

Resource    Device  
I/O Port 0x00000070-0x00000070  Motherboard resources   
I/O Port 0x00000070-0x00000070  System CMOS/real time clock 
        
I/O Port 0x0000E000-0x0000EFFF  PCI Express Root Port   
I/O Port 0x0000E000-0x0000EFFF  Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   
        
Memory Address 0xFD000000-0xFDABFFFF    Motherboard resources   
Memory Address 0xFD000000-0xFDABFFFF    PCI Express Root Complex    
        
Memory Address 0xFF000000-0xFFFFFFFF    Motherboard resources   
Memory Address 0xFF000000-0xFFFFFFFF    Legacy device   
        
IRQ 16  High Definition Audio Controller    
IRQ 16  Intel(R) Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant   
IRQ 16  Synaptics SMBus Driver  
IRQ 16  Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - 9D60   
        
Memory Address 0xD1200000-0xD12FFFFF    PCI Express Root Port   
Memory Address 0xD1200000-0xD12FFFFF    Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   
        
Memory Address 0xA0000-0xBFFFF  PCI Express Root Complex    
Memory Address 0xA0000-0xBFFFF  Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   
        
Memory Address 0xD1000000-0xD11FFFFF    Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter  
Memory Address 0xD1000000-0xD11FFFFF    PCI Express Root Port   
        
I/O Port 0x0000FFFF-0x0000FFFF  Motherboard resources   
I/O Port 0x0000FFFF-0x0000FFFF  Motherboard resources   
I/O Port 0x0000FFFF-0x0000FFFF  Motherboard resources   
        

[DMA]

Resource    Device  Status  

[Forced Hardware]

Device  PNP Device ID   

[I/O]

Resource    Device  Status  
0x00001854-0x00001857   Motherboard resources   OK  
0x0000F090-0x0000F097   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0x0000F080-0x0000F083   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0x0000F060-0x0000F07F   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0x00000000-0x00000CF7   PCI Express Root Complex    OK  
0x00000D00-0x0000FFFF   PCI Express Root Complex    OK  
0x0000F000-0x0000F03F   Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0x000003B0-0x000003BB   Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0x000003C0-0x000003DF   Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0x0000FF00-0x0000FFFE   Motherboard resources   OK  
0x00000060-0x00000060   Standard PS/2 Keyboard  OK  
0x00000064-0x00000064   Standard PS/2 Keyboard  OK  
0x00000020-0x00000021   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x00000024-0x00000025   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x00000028-0x00000029   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x0000002C-0x0000002D   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x00000030-0x00000031   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x00000034-0x00000035   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x00000038-0x00000039   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x0000003C-0x0000003D   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000A0-0x000000A1   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000A4-0x000000A5   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000A8-0x000000A9   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000AC-0x000000AD   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000B0-0x000000B1   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000B4-0x000000B5   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000B8-0x000000B9   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000000BC-0x000000BD   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  
0x000004D0-0x000004D1   Programmable interrupt controller   OK  

[IRQs]

Resource    Device  Status  
IRQ 4294967293  PCI Express Root Port   OK  
IRQ 16  High Definition Audio Controller    OK  
IRQ 16  Intel(R) Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant   OK  
IRQ 16  Synaptics SMBus Driver  OK  
IRQ 16  Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - 9D60   OK  
IRQ 0   System timer    OK  
IRQ 4294967288  Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)   OK  
IRQ 51  I2C HID Device  OK  
IRQ 4294967290  Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter  OK  
IRQ 11  Mobile 6th/7th Generation Intel(R) Processor Family I/O Thermal subsystem - 9D31    OK  
IRQ 4294967287  Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   OK  
IRQ 4294967291  Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
IRQ 4294967286  Intel(R) Management Engine Interface #1 OK  
IRQ 4294967294  PCI Express Root Port   OK  
IRQ 8   System CMOS/real time clock OK  
IRQ 4294967289  Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
IRQ 55  Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System OK  
...
...
IRQ 511 Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System OK  
IRQ 14  Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller - INT344B   OK  
IRQ 4294967292  PCI Express Root Port   OK  
IRQ 12  PS/2 Compatible Mouse   OK  
IRQ 1   Standard PS/2 Keyboard  OK  
IRQ 32  Motherboard resources   OK  

[Memory]

Resource    Device  Status  
0xD1200000-0xD12FFFFF   PCI Express Root Port   OK  
0xD1200000-0xD12FFFFF   Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   OK  
0xDFE00000-0xDFEFFFFF   PCI Express Root Port   OK  
0xD1328000-0xD132BFFF   High Definition Audio Controller    OK  
0xD1300000-0xD130FFFF   High Definition Audio Controller    OK  
0xFED10000-0xFED17FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFED18000-0xFED18FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFED19000-0xFED19FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xE0000000-0xEFFFFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFED20000-0xFED3FFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFED90000-0xFED93FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFED45000-0xFED8FFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFF000000-0xFFFFFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFF000000-0xFFFFFFFF   Legacy device   OK  
0xFEE00000-0xFEEFFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xDFFE0000-0xDFFFFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE035000-0xFE035FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE034008-0xFE034FFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xD1320000-0xD1327FFF   Intel(R) Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant   OK  
0xD1310000-0xD131FFFF   Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)   OK  
0xD1332000-0xD13320FF   Synaptics SMBus Driver  OK  
0xFED00000-0xFED003FF   High precision event timer  OK  
0xD1000000-0xD11FFFFF   Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter  OK  
0xD1000000-0xD11FFFFF   PCI Express Root Port   OK  
0xFD000000-0xFDABFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFD000000-0xFDABFFFF   PCI Express Root Complex    OK  
0xFDAD0000-0xFDADFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFDB00000-0xFDFFFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE000000-0xFE01FFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE036000-0xFE03BFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE03D000-0xFE3FFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xFE410000-0xFE7FFFFF   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xD1337000-0xD1337FFF   Mobile 6th/7th Generation Intel(R) Processor Family I/O Thermal subsystem - 9D31    OK  
0xD1204000-0xD1204FFF   Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   OK  
0xD1330000-0xD1331FFF   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0xD1334000-0xD13340FF   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0xD1333000-0xD13337FF   Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller OK  
0xFE40F000-0xFE40FFFF   Intel(R) Management Engine Interface #1 OK  
0xA0000-0xBFFFF PCI Express Root Complex    OK  
0xA0000-0xBFFFF Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0xAF800000-0xDFFFFFFF   PCI Express Root Complex    OK  
0xD0000000-0xD0FFFFFF   Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0xC0000000-0xCFFFFFFF   Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   OK  
0xFDAF0000-0xFDAFFFFF   Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller - INT344B   OK  
0xFDAE0000-0xFDAEFFFF   Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller - INT344B   OK  
0xFDAC0000-0xFDACFFFF   Intel(R) Serial IO GPIO Host Controller - INT344B   OK  
0xFE034000-0xFE034007   Motherboard resources   OK  
0xD132C000-0xD132FFFF   Mobile 6th/7th Generation Intel(R) Processor Family I/O PMC - 9D21  OK  
0xFE40E000-0xFE40EFFF   Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Controller - 9D60   OK  
        

[Display]

Item    Value   
Name    Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_5917&SUBSYS_083F1028&REV_07\3&11583659&0&10    
Adapter Type    Intel(R) UHD Graphics Family, Intel Corporation compatible  
Adapter Description Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620   
Adapter RAM 1.00 GB (1,073,741,824 bytes)   
Installed Drivers   C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_b53c057d22ce6f37\igdumdim64.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_b53c057d22ce6f37\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_b53c057d22ce6f37\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_b53c057d22ce6f37\igd12umd64.dll   
Driver Version  31.0.101.2115   
INF File    oem2.inf (iKBLD_w10_DS section) 
Color Planes    Not Available   
Color Table Entries 4294967296  
Resolution  1920 x 1080 x 60 hertz  
Bits/Pixel  32  
Memory Address  0xD0000000-0xD0FFFFFF   
Memory Address  0xC0000000-0xCFFFFFFF   
I/O Port    0x0000F000-0x0000F03F   
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967289  
I/O Port    0x000003B0-0x000003BB   
I/O Port    0x000003C0-0x000003DF   
Memory Address  0xA0000-0xBFFFF 
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\IIGD_DCH.INF_AMD64_B53C057D22CE6F37\IGDKMD64.SYS (31.0.101.2115, 42.19 MB (44,234,800 bytes), 11/5/2023 3:10 AM) 



sometimes there's 'model' specific drivers - and also cut offs for certain drivers/models.  is the driver install you're trying to do from dell or AMD?

You need to install the chipset drivers before anything else, i.e., right after finishing the Windows 11 installation.

yes I installed all the drivers from dell website. I'll also try installing the chipset drivers and let you know. Thank you for the reply both of you

also I tried installing AMD drivers from dell website that their assist software detects automatically and that one is showing the error that my hardware is not supported. It worked fine before

I have installed every chipset on the website for my device and it is still giving an error
